# How to think about permutation puzzles?

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, sliding-blocks

I know this is a very general question, but these kinds of puzzles are the only ones I can't figure out on my own. Rubik's cube, Twiddle, 16... (the last two are in Simon Tatham's Puzzle collection.)

Is there a general thinking principle that applies to puzzles like these? If not, can you give me an example of how to arrive at the solution for any one of these puzzles? I just can't even begin to think about something with so many interconnected parts.

Comment: Maybe this previous question will help: [Rubik's cube without any algorithms](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32731/rubiks-cube-without-any-algorithms/32739#32739). Here's another: [How can one solve a Rubik's cube without relying on guides/algorithms?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/54060/how-can-one-solve-a-rubiks-cube-without-relying-on-guides-algorithms/54062#54062)

Comment: Twiddle:
https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47124/what-is-the-strategy-to-solve-simon-tathams-twiddle and
https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84396/a-guide-to-the-number-rotation-puzzle. Sixteen puzzle: http://kevingong.com/Math/SixteenPuzzle.html

Comment: So does that mean there is no trick to thinking about these puzzles in general? Each one is completely different?

Comment: The answers to the two questions I linked to are applicable to almost all permutation puzzles. The second link is better cause I gave an answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

[Permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) puzzles are puzzles in which a random permutation needs to be restored to the identity permutation by using a limited (or 'clumsy') set of moves.

For example, with the Rubik's cube, you would like to be able to swap two corners by themselves, but you can't do this directly - you can only rotate faces.

A key feature is then to find - and hopefully optimize - the solving process.

For example, consider that you are only allowed to rotate three elements of a permutation forwards, e.g. $abc\to cab\to bca\to abc$. The three elements do not need to be consecutive.

Then $1234\to4321$ can be done in four steps:

> ```
>  1234
>  3124
>  3412
>  3241
>  4321
> ```

Or:

> ```
>  1234
>  1423
>  2143
>  4213
>  4321
> ```

But can it be done in three moves or less? And if not, why not?

It can:

> ```
>  1234
>  4132
>  4213
>  4321
> ```

And, as the OP found, a solution in 2:

> ```
>  1234
>  4213
>  4321
> ```

The challenge is now to find the shortest solution to reverse n numbers, but that's a different question!

My example shows how the straightforward approach is not necessarily the shortest, but the easiest to construct. So to solve a permutation puzzle, construct the 'obvious' solution first, and then try to find shortcuts.

Comment: Well, I assume that question was directed to me; getting the "1" to its position in itself takes 3 moves. So it can't be less than 3 moves. It can't be 3 moves either because "4" has to move in place as well and the first click to move "1" will not be able to move "4". I think this reasoning proves that the solution can be - at minimum - 4 moves.

Comment: You can rotate 124 or 134 first (to get 4132 or 4213). @alexoland

Comment: Well then 2 moves is clearly possible:
1234
4213
4321

 It can't be 1 because there is no way to move the "1" to its position in 1 move. But I don't feel like I am solving this in the proper way. I am just trying things out and stumble into a solution. Is there something else you want me to realize?